# I wish to take the middle pattern of the sentence in chinese character using regex

Tags: python, regex

I tried to take the middle words based on my pattern. Below are my codes:

```
text = "東京都田中区9-7−4"
import re
#Sorry due to the edit problem and stackoverflow doesnt allow me to include long sentences here, please check my comment below for the compile function of re.


city = re.findall(r,text)
print("getCity: {}".format(city))
```

My current output:

```
getCity: ['都田中区']
```

My expected output:

```
getCity: ['田中区']
```

I do not want to take the [都道府県] so I use "?!" in my first beginning pattern as (?!...??[都道府県]). However, when I run my program, it shows that "都" is inside as well like I show on my current output. Could anyone please direct me on this?

Comment: r = re.compile(u"(?!...??[都道府県])((?:旭川|伊達|石狩|盛岡|奥州|田村|南相馬|那須塩原|東村山|武蔵村山|羽村|十日町|上越|富山|野々市|大町|蒲郡|四日市|姫路|大和郡山|廿日市|下松|岩国|田川|大村|宮古|富良野|別府|佐伯|黒部|小諸|塩尻|玉野|周南)市|(?:余市|高市|[^市]{2,3}?)郡(?:玉村|大町|.{1,5}?)[町村]|(?:.{1,4}市)?[^町]{1,4}?区|.{1,7}?[市町村])")

Comment: I do not know why they reject my edit to include this above into my example. Please use this.

Comment: What you are trying to match appears to be an address. Can you explain, in words, what kind of address and which part of the address you want to match, instead of just showing your attempt at a regex?

Comment: from the text = "東京都田中区9-7−4" I wish to match words after "都" or "道" or "府" or "県"(These words might appear in the address text), which is from "田中区" that ends with "区". So my output should be "田中区" and not "都田中区"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that it is too allowing.

If you look at this visualisation here (I have removed all the hardcoded city (市) names because they are irrelevant):

[image]

you can see a lot of "any character" repeated x times, or just "not 市" and "not 町" repeated x times. These are what matches the 都道府県 in your string. Therefore, these are the places where you should disallow 都道府県:

[image]

The corresponding regex would be:

```
(?:余市|高市|[^都道府県市]{2,3}?)郡(?:玉村|大町|[^都道府県]{1,5}?)[町村]|(?:[^都道府県]{1,4}市)?[^都道府県町]{1,4}?区|[^都道府県]{1,7}?[市町村]
```

Remember to add the hardcoded cities when you put this in your code!

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Can you tell me how did you do the illustrations so that I could learn too? Please

Comment: @Anonymous There are many websites that do it. One example is https://regexper.com/

Comment: Thank you for the sharing and I have marked this as answer. Thank you so much

Comment: By the way, do you know a website which can generate a regex for me such as the one they generated for the graph. Will be very much appreciated.

Comment: @Anonymous You mean a website that, given a graph, can generate a regex for you? I don't think such a thing exists. You need to write the regexes yourself.